# web push Api on non internet environment

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, web-push

I want to use **web push api** on my application that will be runned on an **offline** network, is it possible? if yes how to do that? I see that the push service of every browser is generating an endpoint which I believe use websockets to communicate with my application server. but it requires internet for that.
I want to do that on react and spring boot, but I couldn't find a solution **without using websocket** on my app.